# MYSQL: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Not working?

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-update, on-duplicate-key

Here is my SQL query,
below insert or update returns 0 row affected.. where i made mistake?

```
insert into biometric_data.daily_attendance (emp_id, in_punch, out_punch, processeddate_d, worktime)
    values ('A744', '27/12/2019 09:08:31', '27/12/2019 18:56:49', '2019-12-27', '8:48')
    on duplicate key update emp_id = 'A744', processeddate_d = '2019-12-27';
```

wheni say,

```
select *
from attendance
where emp_id = 'A744' and processeddate_d = '2019-12-27';
```

returns 1 row.

```
A744 11:30 null 2019-12-27 8:48
```

but update not working.

**Note:** gone through many post and tried everything still i dont find where i made mistakes.

my PK is `id` an auto field and `index-> emp_id, processeddate_d` `unique-> emp_id, processeddate_d`

Answer (score 1):

Ummmm . . . how would you know if the `update` is working or not?

Your unique key is on `(emp_id, processeddate_d)`.  Those are the only two fields that you are updating in the `on duplicate key` clause:

```
on duplicate key update emp_id = 'A744', processeddate_d = '2019-12-27';
```

*By definition*, these are no-ops, because those are the values that are duplicates.  Perhaps there is another column that you intend to update but are not.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i got some spark. this is how i used to update on duplicate key. so is this wrong?
I want to update other fields except emp_id and processedate_d.. then how to rewrite this?

Comment: @MohideenbinMohammed . . . It is not wrong.  Often a dummy key is used in `on duplicate key` to prevent errors.